Error while configuring CMake to build OpenCV with contrib modules
I'm building OpenCV from source on Ubuntu 22.04.4 in order to use the SFM module, following the instructions here exactly, except replacing "4.x" with "4.10.0"
After getting to the configuration step and running cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../opencv_contrib-4.10.0/modules ../opencv-4.10.0 I get these errors:
CMake Error at cmake/OpenCVUtils.cmake:1582 (add_library):
  Target "opencv_sfm" links to target "absl::log" but the target was not
  found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or
  an ALIAS target is missing?
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:989 (ocv_add_library)
  cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:905 (_ocv_create_module)
  /home/zabsy/opencv_build/opencv_contrib-4.10.0/modules/sfm/CMakeLists.txt:150 (ocv_create_module)


CMake Error at cmake/OpenCVUtils.cmake:1582 (add_library):
  Target "opencv_sfm" links to target "absl::check" but the target was not
  found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or
  an ALIAS target is missing?
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:989 (ocv_add_library)
  cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:905 (_ocv_create_module)
  /home/zabsy/opencv_build/opencv_contrib-4.10.0/modules/sfm/CMakeLists.txt:150 (ocv_create_module)


CMake Error at cmake/OpenCVUtils.cmake:1582 (add_library):
  Target "opencv_sfm" links to target "absl::fixed_array" but the target was
  not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
  target, or an ALIAS target is missing?
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:989 (ocv_add_library)
  cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:905 (_ocv_create_module)
  /home/zabsy/opencv_build/opencv_contrib-4.10.0/modules/sfm/CMakeLists.txt:150 (ocv_create_module)


CMake Error at /home/zabsy/opencv_build/opencv_contrib-4.10.0/modules/sfm/src/libmv_light/libmv/correspondence/CMakeLists.txt:9 (ADD_LIBRARY):
  Target "opencv.sfm.correspondence" links to target "absl::log" but the
  target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an
  IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at /home/zabsy/opencv_build/opencv_contrib-4.10.0/modules/sfm/src/libmv_light/libmv/correspondence/CMakeLists.txt:9 (ADD_LIBRARY):
  Target "opencv.sfm.correspondence" links to target "absl::check" but the
  target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an
  IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at /home/zabsy/opencv_build/opencv_contrib-4.10.0/modules/sfm/src/libmv_light/libmv/correspondence/CMakeLists.txt:9 (ADD_LIBRARY):
  Target "opencv.sfm.correspondence" links to target "absl::fixed_array" but
  the target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an
  IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at /home/zabsy/opencv_build/opencv_contrib-4.10.0/modules/sfm/src/libmv_light/libmv/multiview/CMakeLists.txt:19 (ADD_LIBRARY):
  Target "opencv.sfm.multiview" links to target "absl::log" but the target
  was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
  target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at /home/zabsy/opencv_build/opencv_contrib-4.10.0/modules/sfm/src/libmv_light/libmv/multiview/CMakeLists.txt:19 (ADD_LIBRARY):
  Target "opencv.sfm.multiview" links to target "absl::check" but the target
  was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
  target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at /home/zabsy/opencv_build/opencv_contrib-4.10.0/modules/sfm/src/libmv_light/libmv/multiview/CMakeLists.txt:19 (ADD_LIBRARY):
  Target "opencv.sfm.multiview" links to target "absl::fixed_array" but the
  target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an
  IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?

I tried to fix it by running sudo apt-get install libabsl-dev but I get the same errors.
Does anyone know how to fix this?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated

that module appears to be unmaintained. it is rightly situated in contrib. expect an uphill battle in getting that to work.
